# C++ gregorian calendar year display algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, printing, calendar

I wanted to make a program that displays the whole calendar for a year starting from a given day.  I "feel" this algorithm can be done better than I did it.

If anyone can point out anything I did incorrectly in this algorithm I would appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
const int COLUMN_IN_WEEK = 7;
const int ROWS_IN_WEEK = 6;
const int DAYS_IN_FEBRUARY = 28;
const int DAYS_IN_MONTH = 31;
const int MONTH_IN_YEAR = 12;
enum days {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesdey, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};
enum months{Januay, February, March, April, May, June, July, Agost, September, October, November, December};
int PrintWeek(int startDay, int totalDays, int monthNum);
void PrintYear(std::string months[],int startDay, int monthNum);
int main()
{
    std::string months[MONTH_IN_YEAR] = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
    PrintYear(months, Tuesday, Januay);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void PrintYear(std::string months[],int startDay, int monthNum)
{
    for (int currentMonth = monthNum; currentMonth < MONTH_IN_YEAR; currentMonth++)
    {
        int totalDays;
        if (currentMonth != February)
        {
            if (currentMonth <= July)
            {
                if (currentMonth % 2)
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH - 1;
                else
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH;
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentMonth % 2)
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH;
                else
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH - 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            totalDays = DAYS_IN_FEBRUARY;
        }

        std::cout << std::left << months[currentMonth] << std::endl;
        startDay = PrintWeek(startDay, totalDays, currentMonth);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int PrintWeek(int startDay, int totalDays, int monthNum)
{
    int dayCounter = 1;
    int rowDay = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS_IN_WEEK; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN_IN_WEEK; column++)
        {    
            if (column >= startDay)
            {
                std::cout << std::right << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(2)  << dayCounter << " ";
                startDay++;
                dayCounter++;
                if (dayCounter > totalDays)
                {
                    row = ROWS_IN_WEEK;
                    std::cout << "\n";
                    return startDay;
                }   
            }
            else
                std::cout << "   ";
        }
        if (startDay < COLUMN_IN_WEEK)
            startDay++;
        else
        {
            startDay = COLUMN_IN_WEEK - startDay;
            rowDay++;
        }   
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return startDay;
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to account for leap years, which is THE major feature of the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: You've forgotten about leap years for starters. P.S. August, and Aug. Then it's on to fun years like 1752 in England (and the US). Can't you get a copy of the UNIX `cal` function?

Comment: Instead of hand-rolling this, consider using this library instead: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: yeah, that's true i forgot to mention that i didn't take the leap years.
I didn't want to use a lib. I just wanted to do it by myself to practice.

Comment: @Lucas -- This is not trivial work.  That's why libraries exist, so that you're not spending days, weeks, if not months trying to get everything correct, take care of corner cases, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Paul  I just wanted to do something by my own. I know libs are better. I just want to do some exercise

Answer (score 0):

Well i finally wrote what i could about this.
The program ask and prints to the console the calendar of a given day (0-6) and a illusory year.
Sorry, @Paul is right.
Here is how i answer (buggy) question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
const int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
const int ROWS_IN_WEEK = 6;
const int DAYS_IN_FEBRUARY = 28;
const int DAYS_IN_MONTH = 31;
const int MONTH_IN_YEAR = 12;
std::string days[DAYS_IN_WEEK] = {"Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
std::string months[MONTH_IN_YEAR] = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
int biggestDay = 0, oldBiggestDay;
int monthWidth;
int montWidthes[MONTH_IN_YEAR];
enum days {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesdey, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};
enum months{Januay, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December};
int PrintWeek(int startDay, int totalDays, int monthNum);
void PrintYear(std::string months[],int startDay, int monthNum, int year);
bool CheckLeapYear(int year);
int main()
{
    for (int day = 0; day < DAYS_IN_WEEK; day++)
    {
        oldBiggestDay = days[day].length() +1;
        if (oldBiggestDay > biggestDay)
            biggestDay = oldBiggestDay;
    }
    monthWidth = biggestDay * DAYS_IN_WEEK / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < MONTH_IN_YEAR; i++)
        montWidthes[i] = monthWidth + months[i].length() / 2;
    std::cout << "Enter the day in number (0-6): ";
    std::string strDay, strMonth, strYear;
    std::cin >> strDay;
    std::cout << "Enter the year: ";
    std::cin >> strYear;
    int day = std::stoi(strDay, 0, 10);
    std::cout << "The calendar for " << strYear << " is:" << std::endl;
    PrintYear(months, day, Januay, std::stoi(strYear));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void PrintYear(std::string months[],int startDay, int monthNum, int year)
{
    for (int currentMonth = monthNum; currentMonth < MONTH_IN_YEAR; currentMonth++)
    {
        int totalDays;
        if (currentMonth != February)
        {
            if (currentMonth <= July)
            {
                if (currentMonth % 2)
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH - 1;
                else
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH;
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentMonth % 2)
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH;
                else
                    totalDays = DAYS_IN_MONTH - 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            totalDays = DAYS_IN_FEBRUARY;
            CheckLeapYear(year) ? ++totalDays : totalDays;
        }

        std::cout << std::setw(montWidthes[currentMonth])  << months[currentMonth] << std::endl;
        startDay = PrintWeek(startDay, totalDays, currentMonth);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int PrintWeek(int startDay, int totalDays, int monthNum)
{
    int dayCounter = 1;
    int rowDay = 0;
    std::string blankSpaces = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < biggestDay; i++)
        blankSpaces += " ";
    for (int column = 0; column < DAYS_IN_WEEK; column++)
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(biggestDay) << days[column];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS_IN_WEEK; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < DAYS_IN_WEEK; column++)
        {    
            if (column >= startDay)
            {
                std::cout << std::right << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(biggestDay) << dayCounter;
                startDay++;
                dayCounter++;
                if (dayCounter > totalDays)
                {
                    row = ROWS_IN_WEEK;
                    std::cout << "\n";
                    return startDay;
                }   
            }
            else
                std::cout << blankSpaces;
        }
        if (startDay < DAYS_IN_WEEK)
            startDay++;
        else
        {
            startDay = DAYS_IN_WEEK - startDay;
            rowDay++;
        }   
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return startDay;
}

bool CheckLeapYear(int year)  
{  
    // If a year is multiple of 400,  
    // then it is a leap year  
    if (year % 400 == 0)  
        return true;  

    // Else If a year is muliplt of 100,  
    // then it is not a leap year  
    if (year % 100 == 0)  
        return false;  

    // Else If a year is muliplt of 4,  
    // then it is a leap year  
    if (year % 4 == 0)  
        return true;  
    return false;  
}
```